# How to use custom hook>

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am uploading an image and title for that image to firebase. I have made a custom hook(useStorage) which is used for uploading image and title for that image. I have two separate components UploadForm and ProgressBar, I am passing title and selected image and title from UploadForm to ProgressBar. I am able to make fields for image and title in firestore, image is getting uploaded but title field is remaining empty string.

I am attaching code for 3 files, any help would be appreciated.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { projectStorage, projectFirestore, timestamp } from '../firebase/config';

const useStorage = (file) => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // references
    const storageRef = projectStorage.ref(file.name);
    const collectionRef = projectFirestore.collection('images');
    
    storageRef.put(file).on('state_changed', (snap) => {
      let percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;
      setProgress(percentage);
    }, (err) => {
      setError(err);
    }, async () => {
      const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
      const createdAt = timestamp();
      await collectionRef.add({ url, createdAt, title });
      setUrl(url);
      setTitle(title);
    });
  }, [file, title]);

  return { progress, url, error, title };
}

export default useStorage;
```

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar';

const UploadForm = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [header, setHeader] = useState('')

  const types = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'];

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    let selected = e.target.files[0];

    if (selected && types.includes(selected.type)) {
      setFile(selected);
      setError('');
    } else {
      setFile(null);
      setError('Please select an image file (png or jpg)');
    }
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
        <span>+</span>
      </label>
      
      <input placeholder="Enter title for pic..." type="text" name={header} onChange={(e)=> setHeader(e.target.value)} />
      
      <div className="output">
        { error && <div className="error">{ error }</div>}
        { file && <div>{ file.name }</div> }
        { file && <ProgressBar file={file} setFile={setFile} header={header} /> }
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default UploadForm;
```

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import useStorage from '../hooks/useStorage';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

const ProgressBar = ({ file, setFile, header }) => {
  const { progress, url, title } = useStorage(file);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (url) {
      setFile(null);
    } 
  }, [url, setFile]);

  return (
    <motion.div className="progress-bar"
      initial={{ width: 0 }}
      animate={{ width: progress + '%' }}
    ></motion.div>
  );
} 

export default ProgressBar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useStorage` have a `[title, setTitle]` hook which you use in

```
   await collectionRef.add({ url, createdAt, title });
   setUrl(url);
   setTitle(title);
```

But the problem is that the title is empty. You never set a title. You pass the `header` to the progress bar, but you don't use it. You should update useStorage two take to arguments: file and header and call `useStorage(file, header)`

Update useStorage signature to `const useStorage = (file, header) => {}`
Inside useStorage you can update `const [title, setTitle] = useState(header)`

Comment: I got the problem, title which is useStorage signature never updated with header value. But addition of one more argument, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you never get `title` from anywhere. All you do is send your state variable `title` which is initialized with `''` to Firestore, then `setTitle` which that same empty string `title`.

Did you mean to pass `header` into your hook alongside `file`?